# Is getConstructor() really call the constructor?

Tags: java, class, reflection, constructor

```
public MyClass {
  public HashMap<String, String> fu;

  public MyClass() {
  fu = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public void myMalloc() {
  fu = new HashMap<>();
  }
}

Class<?> cl = // I get class from list
myObject = (MyClass) cl.getConstructor().newInstance();
System.out.println(myObject.fu) // = null !

Class<?> cl = // I get class from list
myObject = (MyClass) cl.getConstructor().newInstance();
myObject.myMalloc();
// fu is well allocated
```

I don't understand why in the first case, the map allocation is not done ? Is there something I miss ?

Comment: map allocation?? If you want to initialize hashmap in first case just call myMalloc(), either on the object or within the constructor. Provided you define myMalloc() correctly as pointed out below by @Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: I wonder how your code compile, since `myMalloc` hasn't a return type

Comment: @Sudhanshu `myMalloc` is nor a constructor nor a valid method...

Comment: You can just invoke class newInstance.

Comment: Agreed, I just overlooked that :)

Comment: It's just a mistake when i copy pasted the code. I will obviously not ask the community for a missing word ! :)

Comment: And it's not working better with newInstance only.

Comment: Can you give an [SSCCE?](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @MisterPatate Unless you provide the code for making the `Class` instances in the list and possible interfaces or inheritance structure chances to get your problem solved are very small. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following test passes

```
@Test
public void myClass() throws Exception {
    Class<?> cl = Class.forName("miscellaneous.so.myclass.MyClass");
    MyClass myObject = (MyClass) cl.getConstructor().newInstance();
    Assert.assertNotNull(myObject.fu);

    myObject = (MyClass) cl.getConstructor().newInstance();
    myObject.myMalloc();
    Assert.assertNotNull(myObject.fu);
}
```

The problem is most probably in the code from witch you get the `Class` instance.

**EDIT**

I suspect you get some class from that list which is a subclass of `MyClass` and that `MyClass` doest not init `fu` when its constructor is called

```
public class MyClass {
    HashMap<String, String> fu;

    public void myMalloc() {
        fu = new HashMap<>();
    }
}


public class MyClassSub extends MyClass {

}
```

In that case the code behaves as you described and the folloing test passes too

```
@Test
public void myClassSub() throws Exception {
    Class<?> cl = Class.forName("miscellaneous.so.myclass.MyClassSub");
    MyClass myObject = (MyClass) cl.getConstructor().newInstance();
    // Note that here the reference is asserted to be null
    Assert.assertNull(myObject.fu);

    myObject = (MyClass) cl.getConstructor().newInstance();
    myObject.myMalloc();
    Assert.assertNotNull(myObject.fu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine when filling the missing pieces properly - so your problem is in the missing pieces. `fu` is not null in this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> cl = MyClass.class;
    MyClass myObject = (MyClass) cl.getConstructor().newInstance();
    System.out.println(myObject.fu);
}

public static class MyClass {

    HashMap<String, String> fu;

    public MyClass() {
        fu = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void myMalloc() {
        fu = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

Note: you can get rid of `getConstructor` and simply call: `(MyClass) cl.newInstance();`

Answer (score 0):

The `getConstructor` method returns a `Constructor` object. The object can then be used to invoke the actual constructor.

```
Class c = Integer.class;
Constructor constructor = c.getConstructor(String.class);  //Instantiate a Constructor object.
Integer i = (Integer) constructor.newInstance("1");  // calls actual constructor.
System.out.println(i);
```

This prints the output `1`

Answer (score 0):

> getConstructor() really call the constructor?

No, but newInstance() does.

> I don't understand why in the first case, the map allocation is not done ?

It is done. You are mistaken.